# Push notifications offline logout

Tags: push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have implemented push notifications using the GCM both in android and iOS.

I know that GCM was migrated to the Firebase, but I have a few questions that should be shared with the Firebase implementation.

Our apps have authentication, when a user logs in and we receive a GCM token we store it on our database associated with logged user.

When the user logs out we try to unregister the token but when the phone is without internet connection we can't unregister the GCM token and it will remain active. So when you open have internet again you will receive the push notifications to the previous logged account. How can you control this, and do not receive notifications after the user logs out even if offline?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you, you can allow user to logout while online.

I searched lot more, no direct way to control this.